# How to change form background color instantly with validator?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I got another probably basic question about Javascript but I just can't get it to work.

I have a form with a red background like this:

```
<form >
<input type="text" style="background-color:#F00;" id="blok1"/> <br>
<input type="text" style="background-color:#F00;" id="blok2"/> <br>
<input type="text" style="background-color:#F00;" id="blok3"/> <br>
<input type="text" style="background-color:#F00;" id="blok4"/> <br>
<input type="text" style="background-color:#F00;" id="blok5"/> <br>
<input type="text" style="background-color:#F00;" id="blok6"/> <br>
</form>
```

The problem is that i want to change the background-color as soon as you type in more than 2 characters in the textbox. I know this is able to change with a submit button but i want to have it instantly, as soon as you type something.

Comment: Attach an event-listener for the keyup-event on each input.

Comment: use javascript `keyboard` event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `keyup` or `keydown` events:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for (var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].addEventListener('keyup', function(evt) {
    var input = evt.target;
    if (input.value.length > 2) {
      input.style.backgroundColor = '#0F0';
    } else {
      input.style.backgroundColor = '#F00';
    }
  });
}
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/oSiroHo/1/edit

PS: You might want to use your favorite library to deal with cross-browser event issues. The code above works for well-behaved browsers.

Comment: I copied the exact same code and for some reason it just doesnt show up in green like in your demo. The only thing I see whats different is that evt in function(evt) and evt.target show up in blue in the demo but just in black in Dreamweaver.

Comment: Make sure the JS code is executed after the DOM is ready. Either execute it in a handler for the window `load` event, or simply insert it at the end of the `BODY` tag.